# Return the result of joining two tables in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, linq, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

Main Code:

```
    DomainServiceAccountManager d = new DomainServiceAccountManager();
    EntityQuery<ListBuy> q = d.GetListMemberBuyQuery();
    LoadOperation<ListBuy> l = d.Load(q);
    DGListBuy.ItemsSource = l.Entities;
```

The code:

```
public IQueryable<ListBuy> GetListMemberBuy()
{
    var membuy =
    from mem in this.ObjectContext.Members
    from b in this.ObjectContext.Buys.Where(b => b.ID_member == mem.ID)
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.ID)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { b.ID, mem.Name, b.Money, b.Tarikh };
    return membuy;
}
```

I get the following message:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AccountManager.Web.ListBuy>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: You can't convert collection of anonymous type to IQueryable<ListBuy>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method GetListMemberBuy actually returns an IQueryable of anonymous type instead of an IQueryable of type ListBuy. These are not identical, hence the (compile time?) error.

I can only assume that ListBuy also exists in the database, but if so, then you can remove the anonymous type.

```
public IQueryable<ListBuy> GetListMemberBuy()
{
    var membuy =
    from mem in this.ObjectContext.Members
    from b in this.ObjectContext.Buys.Where(b => b.ID_member == mem.ID)
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.ID)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ListBuy() { ID = b.ID, Name = mem.Name, Money = b.Money, Tarikh = b.Tarikh }; // <-- new ListBuy() !!
    return membuy;
}
```

If ListBuy does not exist in the database, then you cannot return an IQueryable. Maybe this will work.

```
public IEnumerable<ListBuy> GetListMemberBuy()
{
    var membuy =
    from mem in this.ObjectContext.Members
    from b in this.ObjectContext.Buys.Where(b => b.ID_member == mem.ID)
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.ID)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { b.ID, mem.Name, b.Money, b.Tarikh };
    return membuy
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(b => new ListBuy() { 
            ID = b.ID, Name = b.Name, Money = b.Money, Tarikh = b.Tarikh
        });
}
```

All this is a bit speculation since you didn't include the ListBuy class definition in your question.

Comment: the name 'b' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Error 1 The name 'b' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\farzad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AccountManager\AccountManager.Web\DomainServiceAccountManager.cs 123 26 AccountManager.Web